# Python PyQt5 - how to set corectly size of table

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, grid, qtablewidget

I'm trying to create a small application in python3.8 and PyQt5 and i have a problem with setting size of the tableWidget .
Here is the code :

```
class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 400, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle('OIL-CheckOrder')
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(w)
        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(w)

        self.textbox = QLineEdit(self)
        self.textbox.setText('File')
        self.textbox.setReadOnly(True)

        self.textbox2 = QLineEdit(self)
        self.textbox2.setText('Order number')

        size = QSize(40, 40)

        self.b1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.b1.setIcon(QIcon('./search.jpg'))
        self.b1.setIconSize(size)
        self.b1.clicked.connect(self.File_path)

        self.run = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.run.setIcon(QIcon('./start.jpg'))
        self.run.setIconSize(size)
        self.run.clicked.connect(lambda path: self.loaddata(self.path))

        self.createTable()

        grid.addWidget(self.b1, 0, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft | QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        grid.addWidget(self.textbox, 1, 0, 1, 3)
        grid.addWidget(self.textbox2, 2, 0, 1, 3)
        grid.addWidget(self.run, 0, 2, QtCore.Qt.AlignRight | QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        grid.addLayout(self.vbox, 3, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        

    def createTable(self, pdfsn =[]):

        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(self.centralWidget())
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)

        headers = ["PDF SN", "APPSHEET SN", "IS MATCH"]
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headers)

        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)
```

The app looks now like on screen below :
[APP_OIL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMKSt.png)

All i want to resize table as the blue line shows.
Is it possible ?

Comment: `grid.addLayout(self.vbox, 3, 0, -1, -1)`  that should do it.  But what is the vbox for?

Comment: Thank You very much.Yes, now i correct. Im begginer in Python and pyqt5, i did this app based on some tutorial.If this vbox is not needed i can remove it but i dont know how then add table to grid :(

Comment: you would add it just like you did with the vbox, only use `grid.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 3,0,-1,-1)`